# Identify and remove false positives

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a set of points that represents events in a process, some of them are false positives. Visually, the false positives are kind of isolated from the rest, as you see in the image. Is there a way to statistically identify and remove them?

The image below is just a simple case. In other cases, the false positives can be in between clusters of true positives. So, another way to see the problem is to identify the clusters of true events.

[image]

Comment: what is the X axis

Comment: @IrishStat X axis is time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind ? [image]

If so post your data in a csv file and time available I will see what I can do .

Comment: thanks, the file is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jnp4e-OpBt2cfKKDN-3v9sPXPiO2keA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: must be me .. all i am seeing is time stamp info . Please email me a csv file with two columns      time stamp    then    value .. By the how frequently are the readings taken ?

Comment: time series analysis requires readings at fixed intervals . It appears that your google-drive data has no data BUT does suggest uneven intervals between (possible) observations.